# PWA SiteCollection in WebApplication root

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, project-server

I am about to deploy Project Server on a SharePoint 2019 system. I create a separate WebApplication for that purpose which will only host PWA.

Is it possible to create PWA SiteCollection as the root-site of the WebApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we could select the Project Site template as the root site of the newly created web application:

[image]

[image]